# Simpler way to do IS NOT DISTINCT FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

Is the following the simplest way to write out the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` without using that clause?

```
   ColA IS NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL 
OR ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NULL
OR ColA != ColB
```

Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You'd certainly need some brackets around your and sections if you want that to even work.

Comment: Why would sample data help? All it requires is knowledge of what [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) does

Comment: Be aware that your expression actually yields *unknown* for the null/null case, as will `NOT(your expression)`. Both will go down the falsey path in a case expression, where clause, or join condition.  The third line would be more precise if written `OR (ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL AND ColA != ColB)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` *is* the simplest way of doing this.

On previous versions you can do ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W1A_m8I-))

- `EXISTS (SELECT colA INTERSECT SELECT colB)` for `IS NOT DISTINCT`
- `EXISTS (SELECT colA EXCEPT SELECT colB)` for `IS DISTINCT`

though the more verbose

- `NOT EXISTS (SELECT colA INTERSECT SELECT colB)`

sometimes gives a better execution plan for the `IS DISTINCT` case ([example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204014/3690)).

See [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html) for some discussion on various alternative approaches for this.

Generally I've found execution plans are fine with the above approaches though occasionally I have found writing out the condition in full as

- `WHERE ColA = ColB OR (ColA IS NULL AND ColB IS NULL)` (for the `NOT DISTINCT` case)
- `WHERE ColA <> ColB OR (ColA IS NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL) OR (ColA IS  NOT NULL AND ColB IS NULL)` (for the `DISTINCT` case)

does give a better execution plan.

The `INTERSECT`/`EXCEPT` are very convenient when you need to do this type of comparison across multiple columns...

```
EXISTS (SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t1.colC 
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT t2.colA, t2.colB, t2.colC)
```

... but check the plans to see that they are being optimised efficiently in the context you are using them.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this is of course correct. Not sure why so many people downvoted/closed the question, maybe people don't know what `IS DISTINCT FROM` means.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get what you are asking here by the example. But heres a simpler version of your query

```
Select *, case when distinct_from_v1 = 1 then 0 else 1 end as not_distinct_from_v1
  from 
   (SELECT colA, colB, 
           CASE WHEN colA IS DISTINCT FROM colB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS distinct_from,
           case when Cola + colb is not null 
                then 
                case when cola=colb then 0 
                     else 1 
                end
           else
                case when concat(cola,colb) in (cola,colb)  then 1 else 0 end
      end  as distinct_from_v1
    FROM tab) t;
```

Working fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/aVKsWNvz

Comment: It works in almost all dbs `||` is supported in Sql Server as well

Comment: [This is not working as well](https://dbfiddle.uk/y9jzT_BD), because neither of your two generated columns is equal to the `IS (NOT) DISTINCT FROM` column.

Comment: @lemon its working fine, i represented the 0 as false and 1 as true. only in cases of both nulls its different

Comment: One condition not satisfied is enough for it to be a different operator by itself. Two operators are equivalent only when they behave in the exact same way under any conditions.

Comment: [Not yet](https://dbfiddle.uk/1YOK_qOG): the negation of both operators should bring the exact opposite result as well. In your case you're getting the last three records with 1 and the first two with 0. This is a remarkably tough task to carry out, no mistake about it.

Comment: You can store the value in a nested query and can do a `NOT` in the outer query.

Comment: Edited again, check.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use a `NOT` from the Equals way to write it. For example:

```
WITH tbl(colA, colB) AS (
    SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,NULL
) 
SELECT 
    colA, 
    colB,
    colA=colB OR (colA IS NULL AND colB IS NULL) eq,
    NOT( colA=colB OR (colA IS NULL AND colB IS NULL) ) neq
FROM
    tbl
```

[image]

Comment: [This is not going to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/XpPngPzA), for how DBMS treat NULL values and equalities. Neither your original code, available in the post, is going to work to substitute `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: @lemon sorry I don't follow, could you please clarify? This works for me: https://gyazo.com/34b16e330696c1d7f7db2c4f661578b9.

Comment: Isnt `cola<>colb` and `Not (cola<>colb)` enough for the meaning of distinct from here reason being `NULLS` return different values for different cols or rows

Comment: The `values` table constructor is more concise than `union all`

Comment: You need to consider all possible corner cases for your use case, which are the ones I've included at the provided link of my first comment.

Comment: When you manage to use conditions that give you the output of `IS DISTINCT FROM` on *all possible corner cases*, and negating your full set of conditions is giving you the exact result of `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, then you can say to have found a set of conditions that can substitute this operator.